# solr autoSoftCommit will open new searcher?

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

this is my solrconfig.xml section:

```
 <autoCommit> 
    <maxTime>15000</maxTime> 
    <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
  </autoCommit>
   <autoSoftCommit> 
    <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
  </autoSoftCommit>
```

this is test add document command:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/AluSupply/update/json 
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
-d '[{ "CompanyRoleId": 1, 
    "Description": " hello test", 
    "CityId": 1404, 
    "CompanyId": 32733,
    "SupplyTitle": "this is title", 
    "Id":399998}]'
```

I observed autoSoftCommit, always opens a new org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher, whether this will seriously affect the performance of it?

this is log information:

9117 [commitScheduler-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  – start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=true,prepareCommit=false}

9142 [commitScheduler-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher  – Opening Searcher@648353f6 main

9143 [commitScheduler-7-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  – end_commit_flush

9144 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@648353f6 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_nf:3441:nrt _194(4.3):C2/1 _19n(4.3):C1)}

9144 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – QuerySenderListener done.

9147 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  – [AluSupply] Registered new searcher Searcher@648353f6 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_nf:3441:nrt _194(4.3):C2/1 _19n(4.3):C1)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While solr do `autoSoftCommit`, it will opens a new SolrIndexSearcher which based on RAMDirectory.

So this does not affect the performance.

`autoCommit` will write documents to harddisk, and reopen IndexSearcher, this will seriously affect performance.